# How to get Comma Delimited Array into CSV

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I have this data, and need to get it into a comma separated CSV file, called $filepath

```
$headers = "Meter Ref","Meter CIS Id","Meter Badge Id","Meter Electronic Id","Relationship","Rel Start Date","Rel End Date","Meter ANSI Id","Meter Type","Mfg Serial #","Mfg Lot #","Rel Data Source","Comm Mod Ref","Meter Status","Meter Data Source","Organization(s)"
$psObject = $null
$psObject = New-Object psobject

foreach($o in $headers)
{
    Add-Member -InputObject $psObject -MemberType noteproperty -Name $o -Value ""
}

$psObject | Export-Csv $filepath -NoTypeInformation

$TheCSV = Import-Csv $filepath

$tabledata = $driver.FindElementsByTagName("tr") | where {$_.Text -match "Meter"}
$CSV = ""
$apple = @()

$apple += $headers -join ','

Foreach ($row in $tabledata | select -skip 1)
{
    $apple += $row.Text -replace '\n',',' 
}
```

`$apple` contents:

```
Meter Ref,Meter CIS Id,Meter Badge Id,Meter Electronic Id,Relationship,Rel Start Date,Rel End Date,Meter ANSI Id,Meter Type,Mfg Serial #,Mfg Lot #,Rel Data Source,Comm Mod Ref,Meter Status,Meter Data Source,Organization(s)
1-CAIWFB,PWST441096,PWST441096,PWST441096,Delete,2015-04-21 13:49,2015-04-21 13:49, ,Electric Meter, , ,ORG21672,1-CAIZ66,Installed,ORG21672,SOURCE1
1-CAIWFB,PWST441096,PWST441096,PWST441096,Active,2015-04-21 13:49, , ,Electric Meter, , ,ORG21672,1-CAIZ66,Installed,ORG21672,SOURCE1
1-100FRE,PWST097870,PWST097870,PWST097870,Inactive,2009-11-01 00:00,2015-04-21 13:49, ,Electric Meter, , ,ORG21672,,Installed,ORG21672,SOURCE1
```

The output of `$apple` is exactly how I want this inserted into a CSV file.

However, I cannot use `out-file` or `export-csv` because it is considered a string, therefore outputs only the length counts, or outputs the data vertically, not comma separated.

I also cannot use `convertto-CSV` because that also only displays the lengths rather than the data.

I have no idea how to get each record of `Row.Text` into the PSObject with `Add-Member`.

Edit: Output when using Add-Content
[image: Output of data when use Add-Content]

Comment: I don't understand? It's already a CSV file.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart that CSV file is empty, all the data is in the array

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. I suggest rewriting it and showing a short sample of the input data, and how you want to output it.

Comment: That is all the code and data right there @Bill_Stewart

Comment: You need to write your question like this: "I have data that is in the following format: <provide shortest possible example of data>. I want to output this data in CSV format. Here is the code I tried <provide shortest possible code sample that doesn't work, and how it doesn't work>."

Comment: Also, please don't use screen shots. Copy and paste and use proper formatting (4 indents for code block, etc.).

Comment: I've answered my own question below, if you have a better method, let me know. The data is show above, under $apple ; that is the only data I'm working with. It's found inside that array. Thanks for your help @Bill_Stewart

Comment: @Bill_Stewart The screenshot was a response to James C. answer. All the data used in that response is found above. See $headers and see $apple

Comment: I can't help because I don't understand the question as written, and you seem to be unwilling to change it so it makes more sense. I will bow out at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this. Not exactly how I want it done, but it gets the job done:

```
$file = "C:\mtext.txt"
$filepath = "C:\mcsv.csv"

$apple | Out-file $file 

$ToCSV = Import-Csv $file -Delimiter ','

$ToCSV | Export-Csv $filepath -NoTypeInformation
```

Let me know of better methods.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this as I don't have access to the webpage you're getting the table data from, but it should be as simple as this:

```
$headers = "Meter Ref","Meter CIS Id","Meter Badge Id","Meter Electronic Id","Relationship","Rel Start Date","Rel End Date","Meter ANSI Id","Meter Type","Mfg Serial #","Mfg Lot #","Rel Data Source","Comm Mod Ref","Meter Status","Meter Data Source","Organization(s)"
$filepath = "C:\folder\meter.csv"

Add-Content -Path $filepath -Value ($headers -join ',')

$tabledata = $driver.FindElementsByTagName("tr") | where {$_.Text -match "Meter"}

Foreach ($row in $tabledata | select -skip 1)
{
    Add-Content -Path $filepath -Value ($row.Text -replace '\n',',' )
}
```

You don't need to create objects or arrays of data, you're only dealing with simple string data. That data is then added to a text file (with csv extension) using the loop.

`Add-Content` is ideally suited to this task as it adds data to a new line in the file, and will create the file also.

Comment: That outputs the data vertically. Ill include a photo for you to see.

Comment: My code is outputting the data from `$tabledata` in the same format it is in. The 'vertical' data you are seeing is how it is _actually_ contained in `$tabledata`. Your input data is a mess so your output data is also a mess. You need to organise your input data before you can output clean data. I cannot help you with this as you don't provide an example of your input data. Your answer may well work but it is a very hacky solution and far from good code.

Comment: Input data is grabbed from a webpage. That is the only format it comes in. See $tabledata = $driver.FindElementsByTagName("tr") | where {$_.Text -match "Meter"} - finding the element, and grabbing the data.

Comment: How to organize the input data and output it was the question. The results of $apple clearly show the data when the newlines are removed. If you want to receive the same information, use: -replace ',','\n' and you will get it back in the format it came